# Find a basis for a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to complete the following exercise:

Let $V$ be the set of vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $$2x_1-3x_2-x_3+x_4=0$$ $$x_1-x_2+2x_3-x_4=0$$ Show that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and find a basis for $V$.

I already showed that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, but I'm having trouble finding a basis for $V$. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the two equations gives

$$x_3=4x_2-3x_1$$

the second one yields to

$$x_4=x_1-x_2+2x_3$$
$$=x_1-x_2+2(4x_2-3x_1)$$
$$=-5x_1+7x_2$$

thus

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in V\iff$$
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=$$
$$(x_1,x_2,-3x_1+4x_2,-5x_1+7x_2)=$$
$$x_1(1,0,-3,-5)+x_2(0,1,4,7)=$$
$$x_1\vec{u}+x_2\vec{v}$$

$\vec{u} $ and $ \vec{v} $ are clearly independent, so $ (\vec{u},\vec{v}) $ is a basis of $ V$ and dim$(V)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Find a basis for the null space of the matrix whose coefficients are the coefficients of that system. Namely, the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -3 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This gives you a basis (of two vectors) for $W$. Now, complete it to a basis for $V$ by finding two other vectors who form a linearly independent set of four elements.

Typically, the unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are helpful in doing that.